# Соблюдение прав при нейминге приложения

Tags: android, авторские-права

Суть в том что придумал название для мобильного приложения, но с таким же именем есть только одна гостиница в Италии и больше ничего. Я в этом не сильно разбираюсь, но нарушу ли я какие права или что ещё, если назову приложение также?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что необходимо обратиться в техподдержку.

Comment: Скорее, к юристу.

Comment: мобильные приложения и гостиничный бизнес - кардинально различные области деятельности, посему маловероятно; к тому же, для того, чтобы стать объектом судебных претензий необходимо сначала "раскрутить" приложение до столь высокого уровня известности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все быть может. Я уже накалывался на аналогичную историю, приложение было снято из маркета и я получил письмо от правообладателя, что при повторении инцидента они подадут на меня в суд.

Суть в том, что есть понятие Trade Mark - зарегистрированная торговая марка и если название зарегистрировано как торговая марка, то можно нарваться на грубость. При этом существуют тонкости, а именно:

1. Торговая марка защищает/покрывает определенные виды деятельности
2. И/или закрывает/покрывает определенные страны/географии.
3. Также торговая марка может быть слово или словосочетания или изображение/логотип.

В моем случае история закончилась тем, что я вынужден был заплатить определенное количество денег и зарегистрировать торговую марку обойдя ограничение конкурентов.

Для примера можно порыться в [БД американских трейдмарков](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4802:thpqz5.1.1) - например [трейдмарк на стиральный порошок Tide](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4802:thpqz5.3.7)